# TypeScript | Property "isPrivate" doesn not exist on type "{children?: ReactNode}"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to make a isLoggedIn middleware to my routes components, and to do so, I'm using my AuthContext and add a prop on the private route: isPrivate. However, When I try receive this prop I get the error aforementioned.

I know that I can create a interface and set a `isPrivate: any` but I'm asking if there's a "correct" way to achieve this.

How can I say to TypeScript that there is a prop called isPrivate and isn't defined?

isLoggedIn:

```
const isLoggedIn: React.FC = ({ isPrivate, ...rest }) => {
  const { authenticated } = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (isPrivate && !authenticated) return <Redirect to="/login" />;

  return <Route {...rest} />;
};
```

The route:

```
<Route isPrivate exact path="/users" component={Users} />
```

Comment: `React.FC<{ isPrivate : any, ...rest }> ` ???

Comment: Oh, yes but I discovered now that a prop has the default type as boolean, if isn't defined before! I'll make a answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a prop on a component without defining it, the default value is boolean: true, example:

```
<CustomRoute isPrivate exact path="/users" component={Users} />
```

isPrivate has type "true", so in the interface you can set

```
interface ICustomRoute extends RouteProps {
  isPrivate: boolean
}
```

ps: you don't need to create a interface, you can simple add as a type arguments, like:

```
functional-comonent: React.FC<{prop: type, ...rest}> {}
```